# I'm not able to find the nature of the eigen values of this matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$$
\begin{pmatrix}3&2&5\\2&-3&6\\0&0&-3\end{pmatrix}
$$
It's a $3 \times 3$ matrix

---

Q. The imaginary parts of the eigen values of the matrix are:

1) $(0,0,0)$

2) $(0,2,-2)$

3) $(3,-3,0)$

4) $(1,-1,0)$

---

I tried by solving the characterstic equation but I couldn't find any number that would satisfy it. 
I also thinking if we could take the derivative to see how many times its cutting the $x$ axis But I'm not sure how to compute the values.

Comment: Please add your computations such that we can see where you stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic equation is
$$
0=\det\begin{pmatrix}3-x & 2 & 5 \\ 2& -3-x & 6\\0 & 0 & -3-x\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Because the last row contains two zeros, it gives you a very nice equation:
$$
0=\det\begin{pmatrix}3-x & 2\\ 2& -3-x \end{pmatrix}\cdot(-3-x).
$$
You see directly that $x=-3$ is an eigenvalue.

Next, we also check the other eigenvalues, which are given by the equation
\begin{align}
0=&\det\begin{pmatrix}3-x & 2\\ 2& -3-x \end{pmatrix}
\\=&(3-x)(-3-x)-4 \\=& x^2-9-4\\=&x^2-13.
\end{align}
Hence the equation $0=x^2-13$ gives $x=\pm\sqrt{13}$.

Therefore, we get the eigenvalues
$$
-3,-\sqrt{13}\text{ and }\sqrt{13}.
$$

Since all eigenvalues are real, their imaginary parts are ...

The correct answer is ...